# Still reproducible: No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

This issue has been reported several times and one popular resolution provided was to set server roles. However in my case server roles were already set. Car file also has the Artifacts, still I am getting this error.

I am following this tutorial here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Simple+Message

Here is my Project:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cmtCjqxMX1VYnGc7LuUjA8m9YG4NYKVO/view?usp=sharing

[image]

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**
SampleServicesCompositeApplication pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.SampleServices</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleServicesCompositeApplication</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>carbon/application</packaging>
  <name>SampleServicesCompositeApplication</name>
  <description>SampleServicesCompositeApplication</description>
  <properties>
    <com.example.SampleServices.endpoint_._QueryDoctorEP>capp/EnterpriseServiceBus</com.example.SampleServices.endpoint_._QueryDoctorEP>
    <com.example.SampleServices.api_._HealthcareAPI>capp/EnterpriseServiceBus</com.example.SampleServices.api_._HealthcareAPI>
    <artifact.types>jaggery/app=zip,synapse/priority-executor=xml,synapse/inbound-endpoint=xml,service/rule=aar,synapse/message-store=xml,event/stream=json,service/meta=xml,datasource/datasource=xml,synapse/proxy-service=xml,bpel/workflow=zip,synapse/sequence=xml,synapse/endpointTemplate=xml,carbon/application=car,wso2/gadget=dar,synapse/api=xml,synapse/event-source=xml,synapse/message-processors=xml,event/receiver=xml,lib/dataservice/validator=jar,synapse/template=xml,synapse/endpoint=xml,lib/carbon/ui=jar,lib/synapse/mediator=jar,event/publisher=xml,synapse/local-entry=xml,synapse/task=xml,webapp/jaxws=war,registry/resource=zip,synapse/configuration=xml,service/axis2=aar,synapse/lib=zip,synapse/sequenceTemplate=xml,event/execution-plan=siddhiql,service/dataservice=dbs,web/application=war,lib/library/bundle=jar</artifact.types>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.SampleServices.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>HealthcareAPI</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.SampleServices.endpoint</groupId>
      <artifactId>QueryDoctorEP</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-maven2-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-nexus-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-maven2-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-nexus-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <buildcommands />
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.distribution.project.nature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-car-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>car</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>car</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration />
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-car-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <carbonServers>
            <CarbonServer>
              <trustStorePath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</trustStorePath>
              <trustStorePassword>wso2carbon</trustStorePassword>
              <trustStoreType>JKS</trustStoreType>
              <serverUrl>https://localhost:9443</serverUrl>
              <userName>admin</userName>
              <password>admin</password>
              <operation>deploy</operation>
            </CarbonServer>
          </carbonServers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml files to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our conversation, you have been deploying the artifacts in Api manager product instead of Enterprise Integrator product, hence the far file was not deployed.

Please choose the proper product for your deployment.